# Which Applications are accessing the microphone in OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, security

I want to list the application names / process ids that are accessing any microphone / sound input device.  This would be great if it were a Terminal command (like lsof) but even an application would be fine, especially if it is managed through Homebrew.

Comment: Important because of http://9to5google.com/2015/06/22/chrome-ok-google-hotwording-extension-privacy-concerns-confusion/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oversight](https://objective-see.com/products/oversight.html) is an app that can notify when apps begin using microphone or webcam privileges. I don't know how it's implemented under the hood, though.

Comment: It does not always tell what specific app now uses it. Also log is empty for me.